# Finding the intersection of two great circles on the Earth

Tags: c#, c++, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to find the intersection between two great circles on a map. As an example, I tried to find where the route from San Francisco to Barcelona intersects with the route from Los Angeles to Paris.

[image]

I was able to find the answer by querying a postGIS database:

```
select
    st_astext(st_intersection(
      st_segmentize(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-122.4194 37.7749, 2.1686 41.3874)'),10)
      ,st_segmentize(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-118.4079 35.9434, 2.3522 48.8566)'),10)));
```

This gives me the point

> POINT(-81.92999062964206 58.49293500104545)

Which seems reasonable.

The problem is that I am only able to do this calculation by querying a database. I'm looking for a way to do this same calculation directly in a program, preferably using C# or C++.

All the libraries I've tried does the calculation using 2D lines and so the intersection will be placed much further south-west.

Comment: This is a seriously difficult calculation because the Earth is not a sphere. If you really want to do this then you should search for the term *geodesy*. Be prepared for some serious numerical analysis (since the calculations are so involved). And since the Earth is an irregular shape any two sources may disagree on how to model its shape so it may be difficult to duplicate your database query exactly (assuming that is your intent).

Comment: see https://www.google.com/search?q=intersection+of+great+circles+site:stackoverflow.com https://www.google.com/search?q=intersection+of+great+circles+site:math.stackexchange.com for some examples

Comment: @john But how is postGIS able to give me the result back so quickly? Surly they are using some library on the server side that does the calculation?

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not asking for the details on how to implement this my self from scratch, I'm just looking for a way do get a similar result without having to deploy and query a database to do a calculation for me.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious -- have you asked the admins of the PostGIS database what calculation they use?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit I'm sure they are, or maybe they are using their own code. What I'm saying is that this calculation, done properly, is a bit more complicated than looking up the formula in some math textbook, and using that.

Comment: @john I assumed these types of calculation were common enough that there would exist libraries for doing them outside of a database, but maybe I was wrong. Thanks for your time and input though, appreciate it!

Comment: PostGIS is using the open source lib libGEOS internally https://libgeos.org/ The relevant point in the code is OverlayPoints.cpp/OverlayPoints::computeIntersection as far as I was able to track this down. However, it is still not completely clear how it works. AFAIK they raster the world with a given precision, do projections to the next raster point and check if the second line dontains this point as well. But I am not quite sure because in my understanding that would yield into a crazy huge amount of checks for high precision. I am sure, there's also some sort of optimization in the code.